# python venv creates a not-empty venv

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

I don't know much about python virtual environments so any help would be appreciated.

In my .bash_profile file there is an alias:

`alias python='python3'`

So I always use "python" command instead of "python3" command.

But, in terminal when I run:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python

$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
```

I don't know why are they different, and when I create a virtual environment with:

```
$ python -m venv myvenv
```

It doesn't create a venv with just "pip" and "setuptools" packages, otherwise it does OK when a run with:

```
$ python3 -m venv myvenv
```

Has anybody know what happend?

Many thanks!

Comment: which python version you are using?

Comment: @merin Python 3.7.2

Comment: did you install virtualenv?

Comment: I suspect either your alias isnt set properly or your env file isnt being loaded. Normally when you do which on an alias it would show you that alias like `which type` for me shows `type='whence -v'`

Comment: My intuition is that your python3 isn't installed in the right path. I tried to replicate your problem but I managed to create a venv easilly.